# HTML Javascript Button Alert Onlcick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on writing a simple chrome extension, so the JS has to be written in it's own .js document.

`options.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Proxy Extension</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
        <script src = "jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src = "options.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="settings" align="center">
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="info" id="Addy" placeholder="Address">
            <input type="number" class="info" id="Port" placeholder="Port" max="9999">
            <p></p>
        </form>
            <input type="button" id="box" value="Update">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`options.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").click(function(){
        alert("placeholder");
    });
});
```

Functionality is supposed to be super simple. Press the button: get an alert. Problem is, I'm not getting an alert.

Comment: jQuery does not have onclick.... read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/). The error in the console should have alerted you to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-order you script loading.

The scripts are executed as encountered, so your options.js file is executed before loading the jQuery library and thus fails at the `$(document)` line.

If you open the dev tools you will see the error in the console log.

So use

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="options.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is because jquery should be loaded BEFORE your script.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting this console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

To fix this, import the jQuery library BEFORE options.js.

```
<script src = "jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src = "options.js"></script>
```

Also, change the options.js code to **.click()** not .onclick()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").click(function(){
        alert("placeholder");
    });
});
```

Comment: you mean import the jQuery library **BEFORE** options.js